# How can i replace "this" in android studio?

Tags: android

How can i not overlap two uses of this, in same java file. I am trying to make it work by replacing "this" with something else but no working.

Comment: what are you saying ,hah? , please edit your question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm pretty sure you can't and I don't understand why would you want do do so.

You can only change it to 
`YourClassName.this`

Comment: This post should be a comment.